# Detect programmatically whether take_over_get_content is true or false

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, android-jetpack

It seems that some Android devices come with `take_over_get_content` true, and some with it set to false.

**From an Android app**, is it possible to detect what value it has?
I think it is not readable directly, but it may be guessable via some side-effects (for instance some queryable feature being available indirectly depends on the state of the flag) or even via model statistics (example: Probably true if Pixel, probably false if Samsung).

For reference, it can be checked easily via ADB:

```
adb shell cmd device_config get storage_native_boot take_over_get_content
```

Context:

- When `take_over_get_content` is false, the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` intent is the best picker (allows picking pictures from other apps).
- When `take_over_get_content` is true, the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` intent is the best picker (does not [lose EXIF location](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243294058)).

Comment: There are tens of thousands of Android device models. How many did you test to come up with your "Context"? Note: I'm not questioning the existence of `take_over_get_content`, but more your analysis of "best picker", given that device manufacturers can make lots of other changes.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks for your comment, by the way you're my hero! We received 10+ reports from users about EXIF location loss. Even though we haven't tested on thousands of devices, so far both bullets are true on all devices we have tried. If there are exceptions we would love to hear about them sooner rather than later. By the way this is for https://github.com/commons-app/apps-android-commons/issues/5196

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that you can't get that info without having a rooted device, and actually running that shell command. However, what you should be able to do is check the MediaProvider version, since that feature is only available on with version `330811020`.

You should be able to do this with `PackageManager`, but I'm not 100% sure if you'll need any extra permissions to be able to query other apps installed on the device:

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.google.android.mediaprovider", 0);
return packageInfo.versionName;
```

Comment: Thanks for a good start! Even if we get the the version of MediaProvider that's installed it won't help much. That's because even if version with Photo Picker is installed on the device, the mentioned feature flag could still be turned off.

Comment: While that's true, there is not way for you to check that flag at runtime. The only other thing you can do is add a setting that's called something like "use legacy photo picker", and they use would be responsible for making that choice

Comment: kaartic is right, almost any device has a high-enough software version, the real question is whether the manufacturer of that device happens to have decided to turn the feature on or not. Typically I believe that most Pixel phones have the feature on, and most Samsung phones have the feature off, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @user496854 Providing that option would mean there should be some way to invoke the legacy photo picker (the DocumentsUi based one). There doesn't seem to be a way to do that when the feature flag in question is turned on. If I'm missing anything, please clarify.

Comment: It's my understanding that the `take_over_get_content` flag isn't hardwired into the device config, and can be changed by Google on the server end. If I'm wrong about that, then there is no way to check that flag without running ADB commands, or having a rooted device